# Logging soap request URL

Tags: java, spring, logging, soap, log4j

My goal is to log whole SOAP requests (header + envelope) for both, client-side and server-side.

You can do so by adding the following log categories with level TRACE to your log4j configuration.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
```

But this will not include the URL of the request. Is it possible to include the URL by simple log4j configuration or is it necessary to log it manually or by overriding some interceptor?